# How to change type of id in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-identity

(ASP.NET MVC 5, EF6, VS2013)

I'm trying to figure out how to **change the type of the "Id" field from string to int** in the type:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser
```

in order to have new user accounts be associated with an integer ID rather than a GUID. But it seems like this will be more complicated than simply adding a new Id property with type int in my derived user class. Take a look at this method signature:

(from Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll)

```
public class UserManager<TUser> : IDisposable where TUser : global::Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser
  {
  ...
  public virtual Task<IdentityResult> AddLoginAsync(string userId, UserLoginInfo login);
  ...
  }
```

So it seems that there are other methods baked into the ASP.NET identity framework which require the userId to be a string. Would I need to reimplement these classes as well?

**An explanation of why I don't want to store GUIDs for ids in the user table:**

-There will be other tables that relate data to the users table via a foreign key. (When users save content on the site.) I see no reason to use the larger field type and spend extra database space with no clear advantages. (I know that there are other posts about using GUIDs vs int ids, but it seems like many suggest that int ids are faster and use less space, which still leaves me wondering.)

-I plan to expose a restful endpoint to allow users to retrieve data about a particular user. I think:

```
/users/123/name
```

is cleaner than

```
/users/{af54c891-69ba-4ddf-8cb6-00d368e58d77}/name
```

Does anyone know why the ASP.NET team decided to implement IDs this way? Am I being short sighted in trying to change this to an int type? (Perhaps there are benefits I'm missing.)

Thanks...

-Ben

Comment: I updated my answer with some example code of how to change the type in the latest nightly 1.1-alpha1

Comment: Note to future readers of this question: ASP.NET Identity Version 2.0.0 (released March 20, 2014) includes built-in now the ability to change/extend the ID/primary key's type. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx

Comment: and for future readers, there is a sample solution with User.ID as integer: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/ChangePK/readme.txt

Comment: There is a nicely explained official ASP.NET article on the topic:
[Change Primary Key for Users in ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity)

Comment: You user interface concerns should not be of any interest to a security implementing team!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So if you want int ids, you need to create your own POCO IUser class and implement your IUserStore for your custom IUser class in the 1.0 RTM release.

This is something we didn't have time to support, but I'm looking into making this easy(ier) in 1.1 right now.  Hopefully something will be available in the nightly builds soon.

**Updated with 1.1-alpha1 example:** [How to get nightly builts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/09/asp-net-identity-nuget-packages-for-the-nightly-builds-are-available-on-myget.aspx)

If you update to the latest nightly bits, you can try out the new 1.1-alpha1 apis which should make this easier now: Here's what plugging in Guids instead of strings should look like for example

```
    public class GuidRole : IdentityRole<Guid, GuidUserRole> { 
        public GuidRole() {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public GuidRole(string name) : this() { Name = name; }
    }
    public class GuidUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid> { }
    public class GuidUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid> { }
    public class GuidUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid> { }

    public class GuidUser : IdentityUser<Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim> {
        public GuidUser() {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public GuidUser(string name) : this() { UserName = name; }
    }

    private class GuidUserContext : IdentityDbContext<GuidUser, GuidRole, Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim> { }
    private class GuidUserStore : UserStore<GuidUser, GuidRole, Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim> {
        public GuidUserStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context) {
        }
    }
    private class GuidRoleStore : RoleStore<GuidRole, Guid, GuidUserRole> {
        public GuidRoleStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context) {
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task CustomUserGuidKeyTest() {
        var manager = new UserManager<GuidUser, Guid>(new GuidUserStore(new GuidUserContext()));
        GuidUser[] users = {
            new GuidUser() { UserName = "test" },
            new GuidUser() { UserName = "test1" }, 
            new GuidUser() { UserName = "test2" },
            new GuidUser() { UserName = "test3" }
            };
        foreach (var user in users) {
            UnitTestHelper.IsSuccess(await manager.CreateAsync(user));
        }
        foreach (var user in users) {
            var u = await manager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
            Assert.IsNotNull(u);
            Assert.AreEqual(u.UserName, user.UserName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Hao. Can you explain why GUIDs were used instead of ints?

Comment: So we decided on string keys to avoid having to deal with key serialization issues, the EF default implementation could have used ints as the primary key, GUIDs were just an easy way to generate a random unique string key.

Comment: @Hao - why is the implementation using "string" field in the database instead of uniqueidentifier? is there any ways i can use the sql uniqueidentifier in the database?

Comment: @Hao, thanks for the example, but can you give an example where you use int32 as the type per the original question? It seems like that would be a bit more complicated because with the GUID example, you just ask for a new GUID, but I imagine that the procedure would be different for an int. Thanks...

Comment: Also, where can we find the nightly bits?

Comment: added the link for the nightly to the answer, for int you can just replace guid with int, and EF will autogenerate a key for you, so you can remove the NewGuid.

Comment: @HaoKung, this seems to fail for me when trying to use int instead of GUID. One such failure: This code comes from the alpha of Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll:
            if (model.LoginProvider == LocalLoginProvider)
            {
                result = await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                
            }
It still returns a string for the ID. But in the SPA sample, look at this:
result = await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
RemovePasswordAsync now expects an integer, but gets a string.

Comment: Can you let me know when there will be documentation available for this? This is very difficult without documentation. Thanks...

Comment: So there are two different issues, the user id in the ClaimsIdentity will still be represented as a string in the claim, you will need to turn it into a guid yourself from a string in the template before passing it into the user manager.  i.e. new Guid(User.Identity.GetUserId())

Comment: Or you can write your own extension method User.Identity.GetUserGuid which hides that...

Comment: @BenjiFB, have you had any luck with this? I have a User model that has an integer Id property, and I don't really want to have to change it. Of course, to be fair, I don't really want to use alpha code either, so I'd be interested in a solution based on the RTM, if that is at all possible. I couldn't figure out anything with a custom IUserStore as the IUser interface requires a string Id, thus conflicting with my existing property.

Comment: @dwhite, no, I was not successful in doing this. I didn't even try without the alpha (not sure if it's possible with the RTM bits), but even with the alpha I found that I was having to cascade a lot of changes so I figured I'd rather at least wait until it was no longer an alpha before I invest in the changes.

Comment: @HaoKung - with Identity 2.0 beta1, if we want to use Guid as pkey, do we still have to define a GuidUserStore and a GuidRoleStore? ie. do we need to change your above code in some way?

Comment: It should be more or less the same for beta as above.

Comment: Should i register new Identity models with DI (i use Unity) cause i get error  `The type IUserStore'2 does not have an accessible constructor.` and it seems to be problem with this models?

Comment: @HaoKung I also look at the post on http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity but not sure if I have to add custom classes to IdentityModels as mentioned at step "Add customized Identity classes that use the key type" on that page. Because I am creating the project now and currently there is no table created. I mean that can I modify the current classes instead of adding the custom ones?

Answer (score 53):

Using a [Stefan Cebulak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916477/stefan-cebulak)'s answer and a Ben Foster's great blog article [ASP.NET Identity Stripped Bare](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1) I have came up with below solution, which I have applied to ASP.NET Identity **2.0** with a generated by Visual Studio 2013 `AccountController`.

The solution uses an integer as a primary key for users and also allows to get an ID of currently logged in user without making a trip to the database.

Here are the steps, you need to follow:

### 1. Create custom user-related classes

By default, the `AccountController` uses classes, which are using `string`, as a type of a primary key. We need to create below classes, which will use an `int` instead. I have defined all below classes in one file: `AppUser.cs`

```
public class AppUser :
    IdentityUser<int, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>,
    IUser<int>
{

}

public class AppUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }

public class AppUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }

public class AppRole : IdentityRole<int, AppUserRole> { }
```

It will also be useful, to have a custom ClaimsPrincipal, which will easily expose User's ID

```
public class AppClaimsPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public AppClaimsPrincipal( ClaimsPrincipal principal ) : base( principal )
    { }

    public int UserId
    {
        get { return int.Parse(this.FindFirst( ClaimTypes.Sid ).Value); }
    }
}
```

### 2. Create a custom `IdentityDbContext`

Our application's database context will extend `IdentityDbContext`, which implements by default all authentication-related DbSets. Even if `DbContext.OnModelCreating` is an empty method, I am not sure about the `IdentityDbContext.OnModelCreating`, so when overriding, remember to call `base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder )`
`AppDbContext.cs`

```
public class AppDbContext :
    IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>
{
    public AppDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        // Here use initializer of your choice
        Database.SetInitializer( new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AppDbContext>() );
    }


    // Here you define your own DbSet's



    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );

        // Here you can put FluentAPI code or add configuration map's
    }
}
```

### 3. Create custom `UserStore` and `UserManager`, which will use above

`AppUserStore.cs`

```
public interface IAppUserStore : IUserStore<AppUser, int>
{

}

public class AppUserStore :
    UserStore<AppUser, AppRole, int, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>,
    IAppUserStore
{
    public AppUserStore() : base( new AppDbContext() )
    {

    }

    public AppUserStore(AppDbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

`AppUserManager.cs`

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser, int>
{
    public AppUserManager( IAppUserStore store ) : base( store )
    {

    }
}
```

### 4. Modify `AccountController` to use your custom classes

Change all `UserManager` to `AppUserManager`, `UserStore` to `AppUserStore` etc. Take an example of this constructors:

```
public AccountController()
    : this( new AppUserManager( new AppUserStore( new AppDbContext() ) ) )
{
}

public AccountController(AppUserManager userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
}
```

### 5. Add user's ID as a claim to `ClaimIdentity` stored in a cookie

In step 1, we have created `AppClaimsPrincipal`, which exposes UserId taken out of `ClaimType.Sid`. However, to have this claim available, we need to add it, when logging in the user. In `AccountController` a `SingInAsync` method is responsible for logging in. We need to add a line to this method, to add the claim.

```
private async Task SignInAsync(AppUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    ClaimsIdentity identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    // Extend identity claims
    identity.AddClaim( new Claim( ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString() ) );

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

### 6. Create a `BaseController` with a `CurrentUser` property

To have an easy access to a currently logged in user's ID in your controllers, create an abstract `BaseController`, from which your controllers will derive. In the `BaseController`, create a `CurrentUser` as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public AppClaimsPrincipal CurrentUser
    {
        get { return new AppClaimsPrincipal( ( ClaimsPrincipal )this.User ); }
    }


    public BaseController()
    {

    }
}
```

### 7. Inherit your controllers from `BaseController` and enjoy

From now on, you can use `CurrentUser.UserId` in your controllers to access an ID of a currently logged in user without trips to the database. You can use it, to query only objects, which belong to the user.

You don't have to take care of auto generation of user primary keys - no surprise, Entity Framework by default uses Identity for integer primary keys, when creating tables.

**Warning!** Keep in mind, that if you implement it in already released project, for already logged in users `ClaimsType.Sid` will not exist and `FindFirst` will return null in `AppClaimsPrincipal`. You need to either force logout all users or handle this scenario in `AppClaimsPrincipal`

Comment: everything works, except this `FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid)` always give me null, so I got an exception at AppClaimsPrincipal.UserId. Looks like after log in user did not receive new claim (i added your code)

Comment: Are you sure all the code in step 5. is being executed? Also please delete whatever trail your login uses (e.g. cookie) and see if it is set properly after login.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. User get's logged with identity having all necessary claims. When I'm looking up for user in the controller, it has only 1 claim (at `GetAuthenticationManager().SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);` line, it has 4 claims.

Comment: Ok, seems like you can not obtain user id in controller when user is getting login into. After redirect everything works fine!

Comment: @krzychu I also look at the post on http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity but not sure if I have to add custom classes to IdentityModels as mentioned at step "Add customized Identity classes that use the key type" on that page. Because I am creating the project now and currently there is no table created. I mean that can I modify the current classes instead of adding the custom ones?

Answer (score 6):

@HaoKung

I've succeeded to make int id's with your nightly builds. User.Identity.GetUserId() problem is still there, but i just did int.parse() for now.

The biggest suprise was that i did not need to create ID by myself, db was made with identity id and it was somehow automatically set for new users Oo...

Model:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, IntUserLogin, IntUserRole, IntUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
    }
    public ApplicationUser(string name) : this() { UserName = name; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IntUserContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {

    }
}

private class IntRole : IdentityRole<int, IntUserRole>
{
    public IntRole()
    {
    }
    public IntRole(string name) : this() { Name = name; }
}
private class IntUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
private class IntUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
private class IntUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
private class IntUserContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IntRole, int, IntUserLogin, IntUserRole, IntUserClaim>
{
    public IntUserContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}
private class IntUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, IntRole, int, IntUserLogin, IntUserRole, IntUserClaim>
{
    public IntUserStore(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
}
private class IntRoleStore : RoleStore<IntRole, int, IntUserRole>
{
    public IntRoleStore(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
        public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>(new IntUserStore(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> UserManager { get; private set; }
```

Hope release build will come soon :D...

P.S. Can't write comments so i did an answer, sorry.

Comment: Stefan, what did you do for the `ChallengeResult()` and `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()`. Both methods are located in `AccountController()` and both expect the `UserId` as parameter but as a `string`. So you can't convert it to `int`. Did you parse `User.Identity.GetUserId()` to int as well or not?

Comment: No, to be honest i didn't even noticed this, but authentication by Google and Facebook is working correctly. I think i won't change it but rather wait for release build. This seems to have someting to do with XSRF protection.

Comment: What do you mean with wait for release build? The newest version of `asp.net-identity` just got released yesterday?

Comment: That's a nice suprise :], already done update. String id is still there by default in User.Identity.GetUserId(), i wonder if i need to create my own IdentityExtensions to change this. I will probably wait for examples, don't have time to work on it right now.

Comment: has anyone actually gotten this to work?  I just tried and I am getting a "Sequence contains no matching element" error when updating my database.

Comment: @William I'm already using this in one of my projects and it works nice so far, but i was creating new database with this instead of updating an existing one.

Comment: @William, check out my answer. If you encounter any problems, let me know in comments.

Answer (score 4):

As stated [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity):

> In Visual Studio 2013, the default web application uses a string value
>   for the key for user accounts. ASP.NET Identity enables you to change
>   the type of the key to meet your data requirements. For example, you
>   can change the type of the key from a string to an integer.

This topic on the above link shows how to start with the default web application and change the user account key to an integer. You can use the same modifications to implement any type of key in your project. It shows how to make these changes in the default web application, but you could apply similar modifications to a customized application. It shows the changes needed when working with MVC or Web Forms.

Comment: This text should be cited properly.

Comment: @Necreaux what do you mean "cited properly"? please be clear.

Comment: @t.durden that first paragraph was copy/paste from the linked website without attribution and technically plagiarism. Since nobody has done anything since this comment, I went ahead and attempted to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have to :

-Change the type of the key to int in the Identity user class 
-Add customized Identity classes that use int as key 
-Change the context class and user manager to use int as key 
-Change start-up configuration to use int as key 
-Change the AccountController to pass int as key

[here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity)  is link where all steps are explained to achieve this.