# Need to change Asp.Net Identity (RTM) User Id from nvarchar(128) to uniqueidentifier

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

Using Asp.Net Identity 1.0 (RTM version). The default implementation creates an AspNetUsers table. The Id column type is nvarchar(128).

When the database and tables are being created, I would simply like to change the type of the User Id to be uniqueidentifier instead of nvarchar(128). I have attempted this using .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier") within the OnModelCreating override... but it throws errors.

Microsoft indicates that it is easy... but I would tend to disagree...

> http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity
>
> Since you control the database schema, common tasks such as changing
>   table names or changing the data type of primary keys is simple to do.

So according to their extremely brief and completely non-technical documentation this seems to be a common task, changing the data type of a primary key... but there doesn't seem to be anything simple about it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update to the latest nightly bits, you can try out the new 1.1-alpha1 apis which should make this easier now: Here's what plugging in Guids instead of strings should look like for example

```
    public class GuidRole : IdentityRole<Guid, GuidUserRole> { 
        public GuidRole() {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public GuidRole(string name) : this() { Name = name; }
    }
    public class GuidUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid> { }
    public class GuidUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid> { }
    public class GuidUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid> { }

    public class GuidUser : IdentityUser<Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim> {
        public GuidUser() {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public GuidUser(string name) : this() { UserName = name; }
    }

    private class GuidUserContext : IdentityDbContext<GuidUser, GuidRole, Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim> { }
    private class GuidUserStore : UserStore<GuidUser, GuidRole, Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim> {
        public GuidUserStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context) {
        }
    }
    private class GuidRoleStore : RoleStore<GuidRole, Guid, GuidUserRole> {
        public GuidRoleStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context) {
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task CustomUserGuidKeyTest() {
        var manager = new UserManager<GuidUser, Guid>(new GuidUserStore(new GuidUserContext()));
        GuidUser[] users = {
            new GuidUser() { UserName = "test" },
            new GuidUser() { UserName = "test1" }, 
            new GuidUser() { UserName = "test2" },
            new GuidUser() { UserName = "test3" }
            };
        foreach (var user in users) {
            UnitTestHelper.IsSuccess(await manager.CreateAsync(user));
        }
        foreach (var user in users) {
            var u = await manager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
            Assert.IsNotNull(u);
            Assert.AreEqual(u.UserName, user.UserName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hao Kung from the ASP.NET team has posted here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553424/how-to-change-type-of-id-in-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-identityus/19577113#19577113) that you need to implement your own `IUserStore`, but he is working on making it easier for the 1.1 version.

I believe you will not only have to implement `IUserStore`, to me it looks like you need your own `UserStore` implementation as the `UserStore<TUser>` is restricted to `IdentityUser`.

If I am correct this means that you need to at least implement `IUserStore`, `IUserPasswordStore`, `IUserSecurityStampStore` and `IUserLoginStore`.

It's 14 methods, most of them pretty straight forward to implement though. Note this would not be a complete replacement for `UserStore<TUser>`, it's only what you need to support the parts that are used from the `AccountController` from the default templates.

I have a project on [GitHub](https://github.com/onybo/Asp.Net-Identity-sample-app/tree/master/WebApplication) where I tried this myself, i.e. I implemented a UserStore that use MongoDb instead of EntityFramework for persistence.