# Possible problems after changing type of id from string (GUID) to int?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, guid, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-identity-3

I use ASP.NET Identity 2.0 in my MVC5 project and wanted to change the data type of id field of AspNetUsers from string (GUID) to int because of that I have some tables related to AspNetUsers table. I look at many pages as on [How to change type of id in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553424/how-to-change-type-of-id-in-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-identityus) but it seems to be not easy to apply. On the other hand, I see that changing the data type of id field of AspNetUsers entity will not be enough as there are some pk/fk relations between the other identity types i.e. AspNetUserRoles, ApplicationGroupRoles, etc.. In that case, should I use the original data type for identity tables and change the id type for my tables from int to string? Or how can I change data type of all of the identity tables easily in ASP.NET Identity 2.0? If this is easier in version 3.0 I can also use it.

Comment: Why you don't let Users with string Id and all others tables with int Id?

Comment: @LucianBumb I am not sure if it is good idea for PK/FK relation. So, I think the best idea is to use int for custom tables and convert id type from string to int for asp.net identity tables. Any suggestion?

Comment: mate, I struggle a lot to do what you are trying now, because I was sure that I cannot have `string` Id in some entities, and `int` in other entities, till I decide to make a test and see what will be the problem. The result was no problem! you just need to take care, that `userId` is `string`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend my comment because, few months ago I was trying to do the same.

In my case, I was not sure if I can create relations `string` -> `int`, comming from Database first, and used to create relations between productId(int) and userId(int), I wanted to have int ids all over.

Mate you can let `userId` like `string` and create relations like this;

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public string SalesManId {get;set;}
  [ForeignKey("SalesManId ")]
  public virtual ApplicationUser SalesMan {get;set;}
}
```

Here is the `Customer` Entity, and I have declared a navigation property!
So, the `SalesManId` is of type `string`. In this way you can create all your relations with `ApplicationUser` class.

If you still want to change to int, here is a youtube tutorial, which I followed few months ago and I manged to change from string to int

[YouTube tutorial-How to change UserId from string to int](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5In3-my096E)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Actually I had encountered many problems during pk/fk relationships creations and I think it would be better if I solve the problem by changing data type of identity tables from string to int. >>>

Comment: So, I look at the original post on http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity but not sure if I have to add the custom classes to IdentityModels explained at step "Add customized Identity classes that use the key type". Because I am creating the project now and there is no table created currently. I mean that can I modify the current classses instead of adding the custom ones?

Comment: @binary I insert in the answer a link to the tutorial which is telling step by step how to do it.