# How to change the type of the user's id from string to int in Asp.NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I have an application written using C# on the top on Asp.Net Core 2.2. The application was written on the top of Core 2.1 but then upgraded to Asp.net Core 2.2.

Now, I decided to change the `Id` type of the `User` model from string to an integer.

To override the string/default type, I created a `User` class like so

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
}
```

Then I created a `Role` class like so

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
}
```

Finally, I updated the `ApplicationDbContext` class like so

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Then I deleted all the database tables that start with `AspNet` and the _Migrations table.

Now, every time I run my app I get the following error

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
>   has been registered.

Here is my Startup.cs class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


        services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
    {
        facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
    });

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

I also tried to so the following code in my Startsup file

```
services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>>();
```

Here is a screenshot of the stack trace
[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19577113/6522459

Comment: @AhmedGhoniem I feel that I am doing the same thing here. There only different is that I am not overriding `IdentityUserRole`, `IdentityUserClaim`, `IdentityUserLogin` which isn't needed really. The `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey>` which my `AppIdentityDbContext ` class extend,   inherits `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, IdentityUserClaim<TKey>, IdentityUserRole<TKey>, IdentityUserLogin<TKey>, IdentityRoleClaim<TKey>, IdentityUserToken<TKey>>` which basicly passed `int` to these ysing `TKey` generic

Comment: as example in table IdentityUserRole ,you will have `UserID`, `RoleId` columns default type of  `userid` in `IdentityUserRole` is `string`  so you have to overriding this `userid` to `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>()` registers `UserManager<TUser>` with the Dependency Injection container. Before you created your own custom `TUser` type, you would have been using `IdentityUser` here, which would have registered `UserManager<IdentityUser>`.

With the change from using `IdentityUser` to using `User`, you now register `UserManager<User>` instead of `UserManager<IdentityUser>`. The error message from your question shows that a partial view within your project is attempting to receive an instance of `UserManager<IdentityUser>` from the DI container, but it should be requesting an instance of `UserManager<User>` due to your change. That means the following change would be needed in the partial view:

```
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

-becomes-

```
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager
```

This will fix the specific error you've shown, but you'll also need to scan through the rest of the project to see if there are any other references to `UserManager<IdentityUser>` that also need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add Migration and Update Database for creating schemas:

1. Define or update a data model in code. **done**
2. Add a Migration to translate this model into changes that can be applied to the database.
3. Check that the Migration correctly represents your intentions.
4. Apply the Migration to update the database to be in sync with the model.
5. Repeat steps 1 through 4 to further refine the model and keep the database in sync.

For Creating Migrations

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

or

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

For Updating Database

```
dotnet ef database update
```

or

```
Update-Database
```

You can get further details about schema customization and migration from [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I tried this solution and when it generates the migration ID is still a string not an int. Is there something else I need to do. Using vs2019 Net.Core.Identity 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your db?

If this done, then just change this

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
      .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

To

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And this is unnecessary.

```
services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>>();
```

Just remove it.